# Cookies replacement question

Tags: php, cookies

My question is the following: I have a pair of buttons in my site, and once I click one of the buttons, it's going to set a cookie using `setcookie();`.  Now that a cookie is set, the user decides to click the other button, which sets a new cookie BUT it has the same cookie name as the cookie the user set earlier - Now it has a different value though.

Will the second clicked button change the value of the first set cookie? This is all I need to know.

Thanks.

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['imgit_style']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['green']))
    {
        setcookie('imgit_style', 'green', time()+31556952);
    }
    else if (isset($_POST['blue']))
    {
        setcookie('imgit_style', 'blue', time()+31556952);
    }
}
else if (isset($_COOKIE['imgit_style']))
{   
    echo $_COOKIE['imgit_style'];
    if (isset($_POST['green']))
    {
        setcookie('imgit_style', 'green', time()+31556952);
        $style = '';
    }
    else if (isset($_POST['blue']))
    {
        setcookie('imgit_style', 'blue', time()+31556952);
        $style = '_' . $_COOKIE['imgit_style'];
    }
}
```

This is my code, and the last else if statement is not changing my cookie value to "blue", it stays green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes .. it will replace cookie's old value with new one ..

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Setting an existing cookie will overwrite it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to overwrite it, see the first post.